# OpenGL - Make two images blend together

Tags: opengl, android, opengl-es2, blending

I have 2 images that are .png and they mix together, The problem is that one overwrite the other. I know that the draw order matters, but In that case I should redraw the icons 2 times ( there is a lot of them)

the black is in fact transparent and drawing a star on top of the other "cuts" a part of the underlying one, In other words, it overwrites with transparency

How I see it now
[image: Star]

How I want to see it

[image]

My blending code :

```
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mMarcaDataHandle);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    aplicarRotacion();
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, marcador.posX, marcador.posY, marcador.posZ);

    drawMarca();

    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);


private void drawMarca()
{
    coordinate.drawMarca(mPositionHandle, mNormalHandle, mTextureCoordinateHandle);

    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the
    // result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: So just to be sure, the black is in fact transparent and drawing a star on top of the other "cuts" a part of the underlying one? In other words, it overwrites with transparency?

Comment: Another question: Have you played with glBlendEquation() anywhere in your code?

Comment: 1º- Yes it overwrites with transparency 

2º-I didnt even know about glBlendEquation( I am new in OpenGL) could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: Please have a look at [this tool](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php). It helped me multiple times when I had to work with blending and will do a fanstatic job of explaining you how blending and glBlendEquation works.

Comment: 1) Don't use glDisable(GL_BLEND) if you don't need to (I beleive it is your case). 2) The rest of the blending code looks perfectly fine, I can't see the problem. Could you show us what's inside drawMarca()? Maybe the problem is in there.

Comment: Sure if you need pixel and vertex shader or anything else tell me,

They also have the same posZ (is in 3D space and they have similiar posX and posY but the posZ is exact the same for both), that tools is really amazing it will help me like hell!

Comment: if i just add 0.00001f in the posZ for every item it works... ( but why?)